# mongo db updateMany with exclude condition

Tags: mongodb

I want to update in Mongodb in one collection with updateMany command there is condition that 6 to 10 users are already updated i need exclude condition that 6 user data should note be change other 300 users will update.

Comment: you should really consider using punctuation marks in your question

Answer (score 0):

Use [$nin](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/)

> the field value is not in the specified array or the field does not exist.

```
db.Users.updateMany(
 { _id: { $nin: [ "id1", "id2" ] } }, //query filter
 {  } //update
)
```